# ServiceStack MiniProfiler Ajax Requests Logging

Tags: extjs, servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

So, in my `Index.cshtml` page, when I initially load up the page I have:

```
@inherits ViewPage
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all-debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.ext.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dump.js"></script>
        @ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.RenderIncludes().AsRaw() 
    </head>
    <body> 
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

All good, I can see it profiling index, a bunch of ExtJS, and the 1st ajax call to my ServiceStack on server side (in /api/session).

Now, in my ExtJS form I have a Customers tab when I click it sends ajax request to `/api/customers` and I have a tab when I click it calls `/api/orders`.

But, then when I start to click on, say Customers tab, Miniprofiler does not add any subsequent ajax requests into the list any more? I thought Miniprofiler can log ajax requests nothing special needs to be done? Why is it not logging subsequent ajax requests for me? I am missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version available through Nuget doesn't support intercepting ExtJS ajax calls.
It seems that there is a [pull request](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/pull/49) for that feature, but it isn't available yet.

Here's what I had to do to get around that:

```
Ext.require('Ext.Ajax');
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function (e, xhr, settings) {
        if (typeof (MiniProfiler) != 'undefined') {
            var stringIds = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-MiniProfiler-Ids');
            if (stringIds) {
                var ids = typeof JSON != 'undefined' ? JSON.parse(stringIds) : eval(stringIds);
                MiniProfiler.fetchResultsExposed(ids);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it out and let you know how it work for me.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a little bit old, but if anyone is interested the implementation for using miniprofiler with angularjs is as follows:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(["$q", function ($q) {

        return {
            'response': function (response) {

                if (typeof (MiniProfiler) != 'undefined' && response.config.url.indexOf(".html") < 0) {
                    var stringIds = response.headers('X-MiniProfiler-Ids');
                    if (stringIds) {
                        MiniProfiler.fetchResultsExposed(angular.fromJson(stringIds));
                    }
                }

                return response || $q.when(response);
            }
        };

    }]);
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! With MiniProfiler 3.0.11 you should change `fetchResultsExposed` to `fetchResults`.